# FlatList Onpress show page with json data for each user

Tags: json, react-native

I have a endusers page where I fetch from an api and how the results in a flatlist as listitem.

I want to have one page for each user which shows their info but without creating userX.js for each user. So there should be only 1  page which is dynamically.

My Endusers.js View:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
            <SearchBar
                showLoading
                placeholder={`Suchen: Name, Email oder Land...`}
                lightTheme
                round
                onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <FlatList
                style={styles.list}
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <ListItem
                        titleStyle={styles.item}
                        subtitleStyle={styles.item}
                        title={`${item.strName} | ${item.strLand}`}
                        subtitle={`${item.strEmail}`}
                        containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Userpage')}
                    />}
                keyExtractor={id => id}
            />
        </View>

    </View>
)
```

My Fetch method:

```
fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
            data: upper(responseJson.sort((a, b) => (a.strName - b.strName))),
            loading: false,
            error: responseJson.error
        })
        this.searchArray = responseJson;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

My Constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        data: [],
        error: null
    }
    this.searchArray = [];
}
```

In Endusers.js View when I click on listitem the Userpage.js should show with the info of the clicked user.

> How should I go on about this problem? What are the keywords I need to
>   google/research to find a solution? I'm not her to just copy paste so
>   please don't get this question wrong^^

Comment: Are you using `react navigation` ?

Comment: yes. forgot to clarify, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send params when you push the navigation:

```
 this.props.navigator.push({
      component: MyScene,
      title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
      passProps: {index: nextIndex},
    });
```

You can send as `passProps` your `item` which i guess contains the details regarding your User, like this:
`passProps: {item: item}`

Hope I helped, and more details on `react-native` documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.

Comment: So I'm still trying to figure it out, but atleast I've found what I'm looking for. Thank you! :)

Comment: Alright I made it work @oma. Thanks a lot for your tip! :) :)